# Armature - automatic weights work terribly

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

Is it only me? Automatic weights work disguistingly. I rigged some models before and it used to be relatively good. Now after I use it, everything is all over the place. Hand bone has some control even over leg area. Thigh bone literally has 0 influence on thigh, but it moves everything else around slightly. Normally I'd think it's my fault, but it always worked fine for me. Seems like it's happening after the 2.79 came out. Anyone else experienced similar issues? Did i mess some options?

Comment: Some example images
https://imgur.com/a/KLJWM

Comment: I had the same problem, I found a thread where different mesh properties were discussed that could throw off the Bone Heat Algorithm. Holes were among them but also Flipped Normals, which was the solution in my case. This makes sense because the algorithm would think that the bones are outside the mesh when they in fact were sitting snugly inside. If after all that time you want to share the file, feel free. I would like to get to the bottom of this, too.